# How to pass props from stateless function component to class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent functional component:

```
function testing() {
  const columns = [{ name: 'test1' },{ name: 'test2' }];
  const data = [{ data: 'data1' }];

  return (
    <Table columns={columns} data={data} title='Test' />
  )
}
```

That calls child class component:

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const columns = this.props.columns;
    const data = this.props.data;
    const title = this.props.title;
  }
}
```

Now `this.props` is empty object.

How do I access props on this situation?

Comment: In function `testing()` nothing is passed as arguments, so `this.props` must be empty

Comment: Seems to be working for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-volhard-expjm
Except I had to rename `testing` to `Testing` since components names need to start with a capital letter.

Comment: This seems to work fine for me also. Please try to add a small demo here, so that we can try to debug and find the issue that's happening at your end.

Comment: my bad it's working. I had another duplicate one that wasn't passing any props from parent. Sorry for the trouble!